# Get minimum of maximize value on pulp objective function

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I'm trying to use pulp to get minimum value `U(X)` of following objective function,
[image: objective function]

where `x_{f,i,v}` is binary value.

And I'm having problem while writing `max()` when set an objective function to `pulp.LpProblem`.

What I do is use python inner function `max()` but it gives me an error. Seems like it cannot be used to pulp.

```
    for each_sfc in self.SFCs:
        vnf_id_list = list()
        for each_VNF in each_sfc.VNF_list:
            vnf_id_list.append(str(each_VNF.ID))

        new_sfc_vars = LpVariable.dicts(
            name='X',
            indexs=vnf_id_list,
            lowBound=0,
            upBound=1,
            cat='Continuous'
        )

        for each_key in new_sfc_vars.keys():
            new_sfc_vars[each_key] = 1 - new_sfc_vars[each_key]

        self.sfc_vars.append(new_sfc_vars)

    self.LP_model = LpProblem(
        name="Static backup",
        sense=LpMinimize
    )

    for each_SFC, each_vars in zip(self.SFCs, self.sfc_vars):
        self.LP_model.objective += each_SFC.backup_cost * max(each_vars.values())
    print(self.LP_model.objective)
```

How can I use `max()` with pulp or how can I reformulate the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic question.

1. `max()` is not linear. Linear expressions look like `a1*x1+a2*x2+...`. PuLP is for linear models only, so it only allows linear expressions in the objective and the constraints. Note that some modeling tools have a max function, but they typically linearize this under the hood.
2. A very standard formulation for a construct like `min sum(i, max(j, x(i,j))` is

   ```
   min sum(i, y(i))
   y(i) >= x(i,j)  for all i,j
   ```
3. Just consult any LP textbook. It will explain this formulation. Often this is called `minimax`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think it's constructive to start any answer by saying it is a basic question, it might be for you if you do a lot of OR but I am sure it is not for many people.

Comment: @Maddo Fair. Otoh, it is a very basic question.